# How to open Calendar control on image click dynamically in WPF

Tags: wpf

I want to populate calender control on image click and bind that value to the text block in wpf .

```
 <Image Name="imgCalendar" Width="20" Height="30" Source="/Images/Cal.jpg" KeyDown="imgCalendar_KeyDown" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedDate, ElementName=CalendarControl}"
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

<Calendar x:Name="CalendarControl"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Visibility="Hidden" >
</Calendar>
```

Comment: call `CalendarControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;` in `imgCalendar_KeyDown`.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I would like to popup calander control like datepicker calander control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by wrapping the image into a Toggle button and Calencar into a Popup. Bind **IsChecked** property of **ToggleButton** to **IsOpen** property of **Popup**.

```
       <ToggleButton x:Name="btn">
            <Image Name="imgCalendar" Width="20" Height="30" Source="/Images/Cal.jpg"  />
        </ToggleButton>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedDate, ElementName=CalendarControl}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=IsChecked}" StaysOpen="False">
            <Calendar x:Name="CalendarControl"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center">
            </Calendar>
        </Popup>
```

Comment: Thank you @XAMLLover your code is working exactly like how I want.. :)